# Dealing with Turing Machines

Tags: combinatorics, turing-machines, parity

I have an *easy* problem with Turing Machines:
Let $f$ be a function in
$\#P.$ Then there is some polynomial-time TM $M$ such that for every input $x, f (x)$ is the
number $\#M(x)$ of strings $u ∈ \{0,1\}^m$ such that $M(x, u) = 1$, where $m$ is some polynomial
in $|x|$ that is the length of certificates that $M$ takes.

For every two TM’s $M_0,M_1$ taking $m$-bit certificates, denote in this proof by “$M_0+M_1$” the TM M' that takes $n + 1$ bit certificate where $M'
(x, bu) = M_b(x, u)$. Then
$\#_{M_0+M_1}
(x) = \#M_0 (x) + \#M_1 (x)$. **WHY ??** Also, for $N ∈ \{0 . . . 2^m\}$, we denote by $M_N$ the TM that
on input $x,u$ outputs $1$ iff the string $u$, when considered as a number, is smaller than $N$.
Clearly $\#M_N (x) = N$. **Again, WHY??**

Comment: How have you determined that your problem is _easy_?

Comment: It is a further unexplained part of a proof in Barak Arora's book Computational complexity A modern approach.The book is [here](http://download.library1.org/get/1376A8F0902AC45ECAB1DAAF43BA896C/Sanjeev%20Arora%2C%20Boaz%20Barak-Computational%20complexity_%20a%20modern%20approach-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282009%29.pdf) .  It is on page 345. Therefore I concluded that it will be easy. Perhaps I'm wrong?